# In django how to get the all the data from table one with the related data from the table two in a single context

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-tables2

I have two classes in my *models.py* which are *item* and *batch*. I need to get all the data of *item* also the appropriate batch_id from the class *batch*. How should I write my *views.py* to get all the data to a single context

```
class item(models.Model):
    item_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_code=models.IntegerField()
    min_stock=models.IntegerField()
    current_stock=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name


class batch(models.Model):
    batch_id=models.IntegerField()
    item_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_code=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

Comment: You probably need to use a ForeignKey, `batch = models.ForeignKey(batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` added to your `item` model to connect these two models first.  *Then* you can think about your view.  Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/.  Also, it's best to capitalize classes, i.e., call them Batch and Item.

Answer (score 0):

You should set ForeignKey from "item" to "batch" Table:

```
class item(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Your views.py:

```
class itemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = item.objects.all()
```